Is it better to shut down an overheated laptop?
My brother and I were sitting beside a laptop. He was playing a game and we noticed the laptop was overheating.
My opinion was to turn it off ASAP to prevent "Thermal runaway" and other phenomena that may cause damage due to excessive temperature rise.
My brother's opinion was to close the game to minimize the current, and benefit from the running fan to cool it down quickly. If he shut down the laptop, it would take longer time to cool down without the fan.
I'm asking this question to learn the best behavior in similar situations, and for similar devices (not only laptops).

You must have either a very old or a very faulty laptop. Modern laptops have so many internal temperature feedbacks so they never have any "thermal runaway" or shut down - they just throttle internal circuits to stay within thermal specifications. And Tcase could be pretty high, 80-90C, so the exhaust air might look a little hot.

You didn't say how you knew the laptop was overheating. However most laptops will shut off automatically if overheating is detected. Its probably better to shut the laptop off if you believe it is overheating since this will prevent the temperature from rising any further which is detrimental to the circuitry. If you just reduce the load on the processor, the temperature may still continue to rise if the fan is not working efficiently. That can occur due to a buildup of dust inside the computer. I suggest that you try to clean out the dust from inside the air vents. A can of pressurized air is useful for this procedure.
